# Is it possible for Thor to die?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-2011

In 'Thor' he seems to have died,

Then , due to some sort of Asgardian force he is brought back to life and regains his powers.

So the Question is,

### Can Thor be killed?

Comment: I say very possible,  Even Odin died

Answer (score 2):

As even his mother can die and his father (the former shown in Thor 2 and the later implied a few times that it IS possible during both films), one can clearly say that yes: Thor CAN die (through age and through force). Although it is very hard to kill him (even more so seemingly than the average Asgardian).